# Finding all possible words from inputted character arrays (permutations)

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, permutation

After reading through several posts I am still stumped with permutations and recursive functions. I am trying to create all possible 3 letter permutations of characters in an unequal length 2D array where the first letter is from the set {‘l’, ‘m’, ‘n’}, the second letter is from the set {‘q’, ‘r’} and the third letter is from the set {‘a’, ‘e’, ‘i’, ‘o’}. My code goes through the correct permutation pattern but does not print out the correct output. For example, if the first 8 permutations are supposed to be:

```
lqa
lqe
lqi
lqo
lra
lre
lri
lro
```

my code prints out:

```
lqa
e
i
o
ra
e
i
o
```

Any ideas on what the problem is? Here are the relevant pieces of my code:

```
rec(character_pools,0,3);
void rec(char** pool, int k, int j)
{
    if(k==j)
    {
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }
    int i,len=strlen(pool[k]);
    for (i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        printf("%c",pool[k][i]);
        rec(pool,k+1,j);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you have a debugger?

Comment: Yes, I am using VS2010 for debugging but I am not very proficient with debugging recursive calls. I can do them by hand much easier. The problem here is that I know whats missing but I dont know where to insert the "missing loop" to fill in the unchanged portion(s) of the array. Everywhere I try to insert it either makes the program crash from trying to access out of bounds array or non-alphanumeric characters print. very strange behavior if you ask me but as I learn recursion i hope it starts making sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

The calling stack:

```
   rec(pool, 0, 3);
-> 'l'   rec(pool, 1, 3);
      -> 'q'   rec(pool, 2, 3);
            -> 'a'   rec(pool, 3, 3);
                  -> '\n'
            -> 'e'   rec(pool, 3, 3);
                  -> '\n'
            -> 'i'   rec(pool, 3, 3);
                  -> '\n'
            -> ...
      -> ...
-> ...
```

**Update:**
Not so recursion-like. But..it works:). Hope this helps.
Assume that the maximum length is 10.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define ALL_DONE 1
#define NOT_YET  0

int rec(char (*pool)[10], int num, int start);

int main(void)
{
    int i, num;
    char pool[20][10];

    scanf("%d", &num);
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++){
        scanf("%s", pool[i]);
    }
    while ( !rec(pool, num, 0) );  // keepint calling until all permutations are printed
    return 0;
}

int rec(char (*pool)[10], int num, int start)
{
    static int ndx[20] = {0};  // record the index of each string

    if (start == num){
        printf("\n");
        return ALL_DONE;
    }
    printf("%c", pool[start][ndx[start]]);
    if ( rec(pool, num, start+1) == ALL_DONE ){
        ndx[start+1] = 0;
        ndx[start]++;
        if (ndx[start] == strlen(pool[start])){
            return ALL_DONE;
        return NOT_YET;
    }
    return NOT_YET;
}
```

explanation:

```
   rec(pool, 0, 0)[1st calling]     
-> 'l'   rec(pool, 1, 0)                    | ndx[0..2] = 0, 0, 0
      -> 'q'   rec(pool, 2, 0)              | ndx[0..2] = 0, 0, 0
            -> 'a'   rec(pool, 3, 0)        | ndx[0..2] = 0, 0, 0
                  -> '\n' retrun ALL_DONE   | ndx[0..2] = 0, 0, 0
            -> return NOT_YET               | ndx[0..2] = 0, 0, 1
      -> return NOT_YET                     | ndx[0..2] = 0, 0, 1
-> return NOT_YET                           | ndx[0..2] = 0, 0, 1
|
   rec(pool, 0, 0)[2nd]
-> 'l'   rec(pool, 1, 0)                    | ndx[0..2] = 0, 0, 1
      -> 'q'   rec(pool, 2, 0)              | ndx[0..2] = 0, 0, 1
            -> 'e'   rec(pool, 3, 0)        | ndx[0..2] = 0, 0, 1
                  -> '\n' return ALL_DONE   | ndx[0..2] = 0, 0, 1
            -> return NOT_YET               | ndx[0..2] = 0, 0, 2
      -> return NOT_YET                     | ndx[0..2] = 0, 0, 2
-> return NOT_YET                           | ndx[0..2] = 0, 0, 2
|
|  ...
|
   rec(pool, 0, 0)[4th]
-> 'l'   rec(pool, 1, 0)                    | ndx[0..2] = 0, 0, 3
      -> 'q'   rec(pool, 2, 0)              | ndx[0..2] = 0, 0, 3
            -> 'o'   rec(pool, 3, 0)        | ndx[0..2] = 0, 0, 3
                  -> '\n' return ALL_DONE   | ndx[0..2] = 0, 0, 3
            -> return ALL_DONE              | ndx[0..2] = 0, 0, 4
      -> return NOT_YET                     | ndx[0..2] = 0, 1, 0
-> return NOT_YET                           | ndx[0..2] = 0, 1, 0
|
| ...
| ...
|
   rec(pool, 0, 0)[5th]
-> 'l'   rec(pool, 1, 0)                    | ndx[0..2] = 0, 1, 0
      -> 'r'   rec(pool, 2, 0)              | ndx[0..2] = 0, 1, 0
            -> 'a'   rec(pool, 3, 0)        | ndx[0..2] = 0, 1, 0
                  -> '\n' return ALL_DONE   | ndx[0..2] = 0, 1, 0
            -> return NOT_YET               | ndx[0..2] = 0, 1, 1
      -> return NOT_YET                     | ndx[0..2] = 0, 1, 1
-> return NOT_YET                           | ndx[0..2] = 0, 1, 1
|
| ...
|
   rec(pool, 0, 0)[8th]
-> 'l'   rec(pool, 1, 0)                    | ndx[0..2] = 0, 1, 3
      -> 'r'   rec(pool, 2, 0)              | ndx[0..2] = 0, 1, 3
            -> 'o'   rec(pool, 3, 0)        | ndx[0..2] = 0, 1, 3
                  -> '\n' return ALL_DONE   | ndx[0..2] = 0, 1, 3
            -> return ALL_DONE              | ndx[0..2] = 0, 1, 4
      -> return ALL_DONE                    | ndx[0..2] = 0, 2, 0
-> return ALL_DONE                          | ndx[0..2] = 1, 0, 0
|
| FINISH
```

Comment: Correct, this is how i traced it on paper. I know I need a for (i=0;i<j;i++)
printf("%d"),pool[k][i]) but i cant figure out where. some weird stuff starts happening even when i put it in the two most logical places. Which IMO is after the recursive call in the for loop or in the if statement.

Comment: sorry i<strlen(pool[k])

Comment: @JohnR I don't think it's a good idea to solve the problem using recursion. Recursion just make things more complex. Nested loop is much more suitable for this question.

Comment: Its required per the assignment. Also, "the first line of each input case will contain a single positive integer, m(m ≤ 20), the length of the password. The following m lines will contain strings of distinct lower case letters in alphabetical order representing each of the possible letters for each letter in the password. So I could potentially end up with 20 nested loops. :/ No bueno

Answer (score 1):

This ended up working for me! Thx @Tsukuyo for the hint. Do I need to ask a separate question if I wanted to find the nth index of a string in the permutation?

```
void rec(char** pool, int k, int j, char* cur, int counter)
{
    if(k==j)
    {
        cur[k]=0;
        printf("Recursive call #%d %s\n",counter,cur);
        return;
    }
    int i,len=strlen(pool[k]);


    for (i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        cur[k]=pool[k][i];
        rec(pool,k+1,j,cur,counter++);
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd better ask a new question and attach a link to this one.

Answer (score 1):

You create a char array which will contain the string you want to work with
`char str[] = "ABC";`

then you get the length of the string `int n = strlen(str);` and lastly you permutate.

You make a new function which will contain the input string, starting index of the string and ending index of the string.
Check if the starting index (`int s`) equals the ending index (`int e`)
if it does, that means you're done, if not you go into a loop where you go from start (s) to end (e), swap the values, recurse, swap again to backtrack.

An example in C++:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void swap(char *i, char *j)
{
    char temp;
    temp = *i;
    *i = *j;
    *j = temp;
}

void permutate(char *str, int start, int end)
{
    int i;
    if (start == end)
        printf("%s\n", str);
    else
    {
        for (i = start; i <= end; i++)
        {
            swap((str + start), (str + i));
            permutate(str, start + 1, end);
            swap((str + start), (str + i)); //backtrack
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char str[] = "ABC";
    int n = strlen(str);
    permutate(str, 0, n - 1);
    return 0;
}
```