# Generating combinations in C

Tags: c, xor

So what I'm trying to do is get the XOR value of each characters combined with the others from the list. For instance: `c ^ e`, `b ^ a` etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j;

    const char* characters[6] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(characters) - 1; i++){
        for (j = i + 1; j < sizeof(characters); j++){
            printf("%c\n", characters[i] ^ characters[j]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However I can't seem to get it working with `printf()` as it outputs a string when in inverted commas and an error when not.

Comment: You give to `printf()` a string, i.e. "chars[i] ^ chars[j]\n", that's why it outputs a string!

Comment: So how do I print the result elserather?

Comment: `printf("chars[%d] ^ chars[%d] is %d\n", i, j, characters[i]^characters[j]);`

Comment: `const char* characters[6]` --> `const char characters[6]`

Comment: That's it, thank you :) You can post it as an answer so I may accept it.

Comment: REALLY dwvaxaz? I have what @BLUEPIXY mentioned in my answer for all this time. Please be more careful next time. Glad that the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

`chars[i] ^ chars[j]` (without quotes) will evaluate to a `char` not a string, so try

```
char chars[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};

...

print("%c\n", chars[i] ^ chars[j]);
```

Comment: `C:\Users\USER\Desktop\combo.c|10|error: invalid operands to binary ^ (have 'const char *' and 'const char *')|`

Answer (score 0):

You give to `printf()` a string, i.e. "chars[i] ^ chars[j]\n", that's why it outputs a string!

1. You want an array of characters, not strings, thus use single quotes
   instead of double ones in the initialization of the array.
2. You had an extra parenthesis in the condition of the for loop.
3. You want to print the value of the XOR, so use %d specifier for
   `printf()` (as  BLUEPIXY stated).

Putting all the comments together, you'll get this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int i, j;

  char characters[6] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(characters) - 1; i++) {
    for (j = i + 1; j < sizeof(characters); j++) {
      printf("chars[%d] ^ chars[%d] is %d\n", i, j,
             characters[i] ^ characters[j]);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Since you want all the combinations, you might take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18928778/finding-all-possible-words-from-inputted-character-arrays-permutations) answer and try again. :)

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842365/calculate-all-combinations-of-a-given-character-set-for-brute-force-matching) provides a more simple and relevant answer.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. I need to output the XOR-ed value of all combinations between the elements in the array.

Comment: I don't see why this should be so complicated

Comment: I'm afraid you misunderstood my question.

Comment: Well you posted some code @dwvaxaz, I fixed it (with the help of other users), I provided two sources for finding combinations. I don't know what else you want. :)

Comment: `<?php echo 'F' ^ 'a';` for example, outputs `'`.